# I can not install the created .ipa

Tags: ios, ipa, adhoc

the last .ipa I created I could not be able to install on my device, as I always created it by exporting ad hoc distribution to test the push notifications I'm working on, but now the last ones I've created are not It works when I install itunes it comes out as if it were installing and then already at the end it disappears, and if I do it through

> https://diawi.com/

download me and when installing it tells me that it could not be installed. Try another device and the same thing happens. Has anyone presented this problem and given with the solution?

**Answer**: finally Get solved by creating new certificates for ad hoc distribution

Comment: Did you make sure your device id is added to your ad-hoc distribution list?

Comment: Yes, it has always been added, just as it was the first thing to check your uid again.